# How do I fix Apache AH00132 Error?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I have the following error. How can I fix this?

`AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/index.html`

Comment: Correct the file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
AH00132: file permissions deny server access "/var/www/html/index.html"
```

is quite descriptive.

The obvious solution is of course

> Adjust the file permissions

and ensure that the Apache server *is allowed*  to access your content.

1. Find the current permissions.  Not only on the index.html file, but also on all directories that make up the path: `/`, `/var/` , `/var/www/` and `/var/www/html/`.

An easy way to do that in a single command, rather than with a bunch of  `ls` commands is with `namei -nom /var/www/html/index.html`.

```
namei -nom /var/www/html/index.html

f: /var/www/html/index.html
 dr-xr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root var
 drwxr-xr-x root root www
 drwxr-xr-x root root html
 -rw-r--r-- root root index.html
```

Adjust with `chmod` where incorrect.

2. When those permissions don't seem overly restrictive and look good (like the ones above) consider that for example SELinux policies can also restrict access.
   Check with `getenforce` if SElinux is enabled.
   If it is, check with `ausearch -m AVC,USER_AVC -ts recent` if there is a  recent  error regarding the file(s) Apache can't access. Conduct more troubleshooting if that is the case. See for example https://access.redhat.com/articles/2191331

Comment: This didnt work